# PHP script stops before final echo

Tags: php, return, echo

I am trainee, learning PHP. As a small project I wrote some code.

I am trying to make a (test) website about cars. I want to show that each car has several options. I have a database in MySQL.

I wrote (this is just a part of the code):

```
foreach ($key['options'] as $options) {
    $contents = str_replace("[OPTION]",$options['text'], $contents);
}

$result= '';

foreach ($key['motor'] as $motor) {
    $nm = $motor['name'];
    $cnt = $motor['count'];
    $result .= $cnt ." " .$nm. " ";
}

return $result;

$paginas .= $contents;

echo $paginas;
```

So far the code. The thing is, after the result code, the script stops (which is normal).

But I don't want that the script stops, the only thing I want is that the final echo also echo's all my `return $result options` PLUS the echo of '$paginas'.

It is a bit hard to explain maybe, but I hope you guys understand.

Comment: Some of your code are not properly formatted, please edit it.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it!

Comment: I don't think you fully grasp what `return` is doing. Anything after it never runs

Comment: So you basically just want to replace `return $result;` with `echo $result;` ... well then don’t let us stop you.

Comment: It is so damn logical. Sorry foor the nOOb question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the [documentation of the `return` statement](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)?

> `return` returns program control to the calling module. Execution resumes at the expression following the called module's invocation.
>
> If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call. return also ends the execution of an `eval()` statement or script file.
>
> If called from the global scope, then execution of the current script file is ended. If the current script file was included or required, then control is passed back to the calling file.

No matter where it is used, it transfers the control to a different part of the code. The statement(s) following the `return` statement in the current context are not executed.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the code to echo instead of return. That works.

I made blocks on the website where the information about the car is shown. 1 block per car

The thing is with the $result echo: Now I do not get a list of all different options in 1 block, but I get for every option a new 'block'. so for example:

Block: Steeringwheel.      Block:Headlights.   Block: Engine type

My goal is to get all these things into 1 block.